# Upload file to google drive from Lightning component - Page redirect removing URL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagereference, upload, google-drive

I am trying to achieve functionality to upload a file from Salesforce to Google drive.
I have done following 
1. Google project credentials (Client key , secrete key)
2. Enabled Google drive API
3. Whitelisted Authorization URL and redirect url's
4. Add remote site setting for google auth and token url.

as per google documentation first we need to get "code" using google auth url. To get that we need to pass certain parameters in auth url as below

```
autheURl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?';               
tokenURL = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';  
client_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXmyclient ID;      
secert = XXXXXXXXXXXXXmysecrete ID;        
redirect_uri = 'https://mydoamin.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/mynamesapce__DragandDrop'; /*DragandDrop is name of my custom lightning component */

state= encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri);    
url = autheURl+'client_id='+client_id+'&response_type=code'+'&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&access_type=offline'+'&state='+state;

window.location.href = url;
```

with window.location.href --> Google authorization window is opening where I can select my google account for authentication, after authentication page is redirecting with URL which has state and Code.
as below.

```
https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/mynamespace__DragandDrop?**state**=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomainname.lightning.force.com%2Flightning%2Fn%2Fmynamespace__DragandDrop&**code**=XXXXXXXXXXXXX(**THIS CODE I NEED TO USE TO GET TOKEN**)&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive#
```

Issue I am facing is I am not able to read or get Code parameter from URL as immediately the page redirect to salesforce and lands to my custom component the URL is removing other parameters thus loosing code value is passed from google auth.

and URL is getting trimmed to

```
https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/mynamespace__DragandDrop?2.fragment=
```

Any suggestion, how I can get the parameters and solve this issue is highly appreciated.
Note : I have used lightning:isUrlAddressable, lightning:hasPageReference as well to get the parameters.
but pageRefernece does not have that value as URL is getting trimmed/ removed before doInit of lightning component.

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm Due to this update Salesforce remove the parameters.